# Rename 'Start' 'End' for the process map

Tags: r

How do I rename the `Start` and `End` of the `process_map()` output below?
For example instead of `Start`, rename to `Begin`, instead of `End`, rename to `Stop`.

Thank you

```
library(bupaR)
patients %>%
    process_map()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a function in the package to directly do this but you can explore the object from `process_map` and use string processing to change the value.

```
library(bupaR)
plot <- patients %>% process_map()
plot$x$diagram <- stringr::str_replace_all(plot$x$diagram, c('Start' = 'Begin', 'End' = 'Stop'))
plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah! Should have thought about inspecting the object itself.